# Download data from Internet

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I am looking for some way (preferably non-Selenium based) to download data from below link

https://www.nseindia.com/circulars/circular.htm

I tried to use the function `XML::readHTMLTable()` in `R` but could not succeed. Even when I tried to see the source of this page I dont see relevant information in the source page.

Any pointer to download data either using R or Python will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: At which step did you fail? Did you fail at retrieving the HTML table or downloading the PDFs from the links?

Comment: Hi Yan, I failed on retrieving the HTML table

Comment: Please include your current code. Debugging help requests should include the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. This makes it more useful to future readers searching with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you're looking at is not in the page source. Your browser runs JavaScript and makes additional request to get this table.

You can look up the actual URL of that table using your developer tools, it's inside the network/xhr tab.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url <- "https://www.nseindia.com/circulars/content/circ_latest.htm"
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"
response <- httr::GET(url,user_agent(ua))
html_table(content(response))
```

[image]

For your reference, you can read this section:

https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet#rvest7.1

Comment: This is excellent. One more question. Is there any similar way to download historical data from the 'Archived Circulars' page? The main difficulty I am facing is that, after you select a longer date range (e.g. 1/1/2019 - 8/1/2019), more data will appear only when you click on 'Next'.

Comment: Yes, and it's basically using the same method: using developer tools and look for patterns in the URLs. For example, that's what I get: `https://www.nseindia.com/circulars/dynaContent/circular_search.jsp?qryFlag=true&curPgNo=2&fromDt=05-Aug-1999&toDt=07-Aug-2019&circlrNo=&cirDept=ALL&sub=&time=1566672201318` and `https://www.nseindia.com/circulars/dynaContent/circular_search.jsp?qryFlag=true&curPgNo=3&fromDt=05-Aug-1999&toDt=07-Aug-2019&circlrNo=&cirDept=ALL&sub=&time=1566672206403`

Comment: You only need to set up the query parameters correctly. e.g. (query date range, circle, current page number, the time when you query, etc.).